# Strange Path Selection in WatchGuard OSPF

Tags: routing, watchguard, ospf

I am trying to configure OSPF between some cisco CPE routers and two WatchGuards. Already tried quite a lot of different setups, already trying to change network design, unfortunately every time I have the same result.

Below I have drawn the network design. Generally everything that is behind CPEs I can't have access. As well I have limited configuration options in networks 10 and 11.

[image: Simplified network Diagram]

As you may see on the figure, trace from network 2 to 11 is going through R1. So basically the WG R2 has the following routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   Metric    Interface 
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U       0         vlan10
10.0.0.0        172.17.12.1     255.255.255.255 UGH     20        vlan15 
172.17.12.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U       0         vlan15
172.17.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U       0         vlan400 
192.168.1.0     172.17.12.1     255.255.255.0   UG      20        vlan15
192.168.11.0    172.17.12.1     255.255.255.0   UG      20        vlan15
192.168.10.0    172.17.12.1     255.255.255.0   UG      20        vlan15
```

From here I can't understand why my router uses this strange path to `10.0.0.0` and `192.168.10-11.0` networks.

If we check the OSPF results from the same router, we see the following.

```
============ OSPF network routing table ============
N    172.17.11.0/29        [20] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
N    172.17.22.0/29        [10] area: 0.0.0.0
                           directly attached to vlan400
N    172.17.12.0/29        [10] area: 0.0.0.0
                           directly attached to vlan15

============ OSPF router routing table =============
R    172.17.11.1           [20] area: 0.0.0.0, ASBR
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
R    172.17.22.1           [10] area: 0.0.0.0, ASBR
                           via 172.17.22.1, vlan400
R    192.168.1.1           [10] area: 0.0.0.0, ASBR
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15

============ OSPF external routing table ===========
N E1 10.0.0.1/32           [2020] tag: 6837
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
N E2 192.168.1.0/24        [10/20] tag: 0
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
N E1 192.168.10.0/24       [2020] tag: 6837
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
N E1 192.168.11.0/24       [2020] tag: 6837
                           via 172.17.12.1, vlan15
```

Could someone turn me into the right direction? It might be a minor thing I could miss, but I can't understand why my WG R2 decides that path through R1 is better than directly via CPE2. It is clear for networks `172.17.11.0/29` and `192.168.1.0`, but not for 10th and 11th.

Moreover when I use `auto-cost reference-bandwidth 1000` then the R1 and R2 swap the roles. I.e. R2 sends everything correctly over CPE2, but R1 selects R2 for all destinations behind CPEs.

Comment: Are the WG units standalone or HA Pair?

Comment: @JacobEvans, yes both are in active-passive cluster

Comment: So... One shouldn't publish the route unless it's active... Test your failover scenario

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. For clarity, R1 and R2 are two different locations, each consists of 2xWG in Active-Passive Cluster. Moreover, second member of each cluster is not connected to our network, only Mgm interface and Cluster interface for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OSPF cost is based on bandwidth, R2 prefers the path through R1 because the R1/R2 link and the R1/CPE links have a higher bandwidth than R2/CPE.  If you want R2 to use its CPE link, decrease the metric (or increase the R1/R2 metric).

Comment: Yes, correct. Unfortunately my problem with this is, randomly in time, R1 and R2 may swap... and then R1 prefers the path through R2. Moreover, while R1 or R2 select wrong path, return path stays correct.

Comment: Some time ago I found a topology where everything is stable, except that once in a month or so, return path becomes wrong. So far the restart of the ospf deamon helps...

Comment: And finally I have refreshed in my memory. Your answer would be correct if these speeds were assigned to the corresponding interface. But in my case all these interfaces have default speed of 1Gbps. So each hop will be treated with metric 10.